# Meteor mongo shell latest?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

When I run meteor mongo I get:
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9

but I just upgraded to latest mongo (2.6.1)

How can I run meteor mongo with the latest mongo shell version installed (2.6.1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor has its own set of dependencies, including MongoDB. This means the version used by Meteor depend on Meteor itself rather than your system. See "updated dependencies" notes in [this file](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md) for more details.